# How to free downloaded image from memory in android?

Tags: android, memory, imageview, android-imageview, android-bitmap

In my Android app, I download images and then set them to `ImageView`s. Now assuming I have the reference to the `ImageView`, can I actually get the image from it and free it from memory manually using code?

Can anyone show me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Setting the bitmap of the imageview to null should free the old bitmap. For a more sophisticated understanding, google "unbindDrawables", a function first mentioned by Romain Guy on his blog and is found in (I think) the source code of one of the android stock apps (probably the Launcher).

Answer (score 1):

```java
bitmap=null;
```

You can then get the bitmap back by using:

```java
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(Resources res, int id)
```

Have a look at the Android Developer blog for tutorials on handling the loading of images. It's a great resource.

[Loading large bitmaps](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)